# Programmatically create node with select List

Tags: entities, nodes

I'm trying to add nodes via a JSON feed. However, I'm having trouble setting the value of a select list field.

I have this at the moment:

```
$node->field_name[0]['nid'] = $drupal_array[trim($branch[0])]
```

Which when I output the node object at the end of execution works correctly but when it comes saving the node this individual field isn't saving at all.

Would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong. I can paste more code if you need it.

`$drupal_array` is used to convert the text input of `$branch[0]` to a numerical value.

This is the inserted value.

```
["field_name"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
            array(1) {
                ["nid"]=>
                    int(193)
           }
    }
```

This is the renderable array output of the same field.

```
["field_name"]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
            array(1) {
                ["nid"]=>
                    string(3) "193"
            }
    }
```

Comment: What's $drupal_array and $branch? And can you compare the $node array you create with the one taken from gui-created node?

Comment: How can I get the array of the gui-created node?

Comment: [`$node = node_load($nid`)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/6) and then `dpr($node);` if you have devel enabled. If not, `var_dump()`.

Comment: I've added these details to the question. Thanks for this!

Comment: What type of field is field_name?

Comment: Node reference.

Comment: Missing the language code… should be `$node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'] = …;`. I think that's all you are missing.